# When does the main client relay its knowledge of TXs in INV message?

Tags: bitcoin-core, transactions, protocol, p2p, transaction-propagation

The [`inv` message](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Protocol_specification#inv) is used to relay one's knowledge of blocks and `tx`s to other clients in the Network. When a new Client connects to the Network, it first receives information about all the blocks in form of an `inv` message, as a response to `getblocks` messages. As there is no `gettx` message, I presume the information about transactions is  relayed in the last `inv` response to `getblocks`. Is that indeed the way the Standard Client operates, or does it just relay the `tx` messages only when they arrive, making newly connected Clients wait to catch up with the information about the `tx`s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ThreadMessageHandler2()](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/a6b4a11385bf44e695c3e47cbd0de6e40eea0b23/src/net.cpp#L1505) calls [SendMessages()](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/a6b4a11385bf44e695c3e47cbd0de6e40eea0b23/src/main.cpp#L2826) every 100 seconds, which causes `inv` messages to be sent to the client's peers.

One peer is [picked at random](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/a6b4a11385bf44e695c3e47cbd0de6e40eea0b23/src/net.cpp#L1534) to receive `inv` messages which reference all the pending transactions that we know about and it doesn't, including the ones we created ourselves.  The rest of the peers receive a `inv` messages which only reference [around 25%](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/a6b4a11385bf44e695c3e47cbd0de6e40eea0b23/src/main.cpp#L2909) of the pending transactions that we know about and they don't, not including any of the ones we created.

A comment in the code explains that this "trickling" of transaction inventory is to protect privacy.

Edit: I just noticed [this thread](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=41730.0) which also describes the process of advertising transactions.  Luckily it agrees with my description here.

Comment: Sleep(100) means 100 milliseconds, not seconds.

Answer (score 1):

The process of announcing and sending data is the same for both transactions and blocks: `inv` announces the hash of an object, `getdata` is used to request the object itself, and `tx` or `block` are used to submit them.

`getblocks` is a step before this process: it requests the announcements of recent blocks via `inv`.